# Can a parent "victim" forgive a child due the death penalty?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, capital-punishment, mishpatim, forgiving-mechilah

There are two capital offences against parents: cursing a parent or striking a parent (and causing an injury).

If someone did this in front of 2 witnesses with a warning etc. so they were due the death penalty, is the parent who is the victim allowed to intervene and not have their child sentenced to death?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104642/discussion-on-question-by-cashcow-can-a-parent-victim-forgive-a-child-due-the).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sheiltot (R. Achai Gaon, 8th c.) says that although a parent can forgo his honor, he cannot forgo the prohibition against striking and cursing. שאלתות (פ׳ משפטים סוף סא): האב שמחל על כבודו, כבודו מחול, ה״מ כבודו, אבל הכאתו וקללתו, לא. The Minchat Chinuch (R. Joseph Babad, 19th c.), on the other hand, holds that a father can forgo the prohibition against striking (Mitzvah 48). However, even the Minchat Chinuch concedes that after the fact, it is too late, because the sin has already occurred:

ונלע"ד דזה שחייבה התורה בהכה או"א [אב ואם] או בחבירו היינו דוקא בלא רשות אבל אם אביו ואמו אומרים לו שיכם או יקללם או חבירו אינו עובר בלאו הזה ואינו חייב מלקות ולא מיתה ע' פ' החובל ובר"מ פ"ה מה' חובל לענין ממון אם נותן לו רשות ע"ש. ולענין חיוב מלקות או מיתה נלענ"ד פשוט דאינו עובר ואינו חייב וכ"נ מלשון הר"מ פכ"ו מהלכות סנהדרין ה"ו שכתב אע"פ שיש לו לדיין או לנשיא למחול על כבודו א"י למחול על קללתו וכן שאר העם אף על פי שמחל המקולל מלקין את המקלל **שכבר חטא** **ונתחייב** עכ"ל וע"ש בכ"מ משמע דוקא אם כבר קילל כיון שכבר עבר עבירה לשמים אין המחילה מועלת אבל בתחלה שנותן רשות לקלל אין כאן עבירה כלל וכן כאן גבי מכה...‏

In his Torah Shleimah ([Mishpatim no. 289](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_51490_94.pdf)), R. Menachem Mendel Kasher cites two works of the Ba'alei Tosafot as well as the Abarbanel on the Torah who ask how the Torah can have a death penalty for one who curses his parent--why can the parent not forgive? All of these sources conclude that the parent cannot forgive (though each gives slightly different explanations):

ובפענח רזא: תימה איך יפסוק בזה מיתה (במקלל), ימחול האב ויפטר דהא אמרינן האב שמחל על כבודו כבודו מחול, וי״ל דהרי מכה ומקלל אינם חייבים בלא התראה ועדים ואח״כ משקבלו התראה בעדים שוב אין יכולים למחול...ובכת"י מושב זקנים: הקשה הגן, היאך תמצא מקלל אביו במיתה והלא יכול למחול לו דהכי קיי"ל בפ״ק דקדושין האב שמחל על כבודו כבודו מחול, וי"ל נהי דיכול למחול על כבודו, על בזיונו אינו יכול למחול. ובאברבנאל: ואפי׳ שאביו ואמו ימחלו לו וירצו הם לחמול עליו אין מוחלים לו.‏

Comment: Well researched

Comment: Kavod is a positive thing so mechila can just mean it's as if he already "paid up". Bizayon is a negative so no such svara applies. Does the Minchas Chinuch  also apply this sevara to chavala generally?

Comment: @loewian I am pretty sure that Minchas Chinuch holds that anyone can allow someone to hit him. This probably also relates to his position which R. Moshe argues vehemently against in which he applies the rules of dinei mamonos to someone committing suicide.

Comment: @wfb meaning he's meikil?(!)

Comment: @wfb combine that with a certain famous tzitz eliezer (or perhaps more than one since ubar yerech imo) and you've justified halachically the modern left pretty much across the board.

Comment: @loewian he obviously doesn't permit suicide, but says there's no obligation of hatzalah because it is like someone throwing his property away.

Comment: @wfb Shouldn't it be *ha b'ha talya*?

Comment: @wfb (I.e. if it's not his to throw away in the first place, why wouldn't there still be mitzvo(s) of lo saamod and hishavon?)

Comment: Maybe he holds it's his but still asur. See also Mishpat Shylock by R. Zevin

Comment: @wfb is there evidence that in the Torah a child was put to death for having cursed a parent?

Comment: @ninamag not as far as i know

Answer (score 4):

I am going to point to a different mitzvah - Ben sorer umoreh ***requires*** that both parents willingly transport the child to Beis Din for both the initial warning and the final judgement. If either relents or refuses, the child cannot be punished.

No such dispensation is provided for in the case of cursing or hitting your parents.

@Shokhet notes that the father has the choice to be mochel on his kavod. While this is interesting, it is immaterial to the case at hand, since cursing or striking your parents is not ***only*** a violation of kibbud av v'em, it is ***also*** a violation of the direct prohibition against striking your parents, and a violation of "Ish aviv v'imo tira'u." *[Additionally, it's also a separate prohibition against striking* ***any*** *person (though Chazal are at odds in Bava Kama as to whether you can preemptively mochel someone who strikes you.)]* These latter three are unaffected by the father's forgiveness of the son - he can mochel his own kavod, but he does not have the power to gloss over issurim at a whim.

If he wishes to plead with the witness to keep them from bringing the case to court o testify, he can certainly try, but he cannot nullify the existing transgressions.

Comment: But striking someone who isn't your parent is not a capital offense.

Comment: @Daniel Correct. The OP was only concerned with the case of a child striking a parent, which IS a capital offense.

Comment: You argue that even if the father can be mochel his kavod, the prohibition of striking _any_ person remains. Even supposing this is true, that prohibition is not a capital crime, so the father has successfully prevented the son from being sentenced to death

Comment: @Daniel I was illustrating only that the source of the aveira of striking a parent is NOT from kibbud av, and that one who strikes transgresses a multitude of aveiros. As I go on to say, there is a SEPARATE ISSUR of striking your parents that is actionable. You haven't saved your son because he isn't being PUNISHED for violating your kavod.

Comment: Fair point. I see know that that is what you are saying in your answer, but I think it's not totally clear. Perhaps consider clarifying a bit

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky wouldn't pleading with the witnesses be lifnei iver?

Comment: @yEz Interesting question. I'm actually not certain if that's the case here - I'm unsure if there's a chiyuv upon the eidim to testify as there is in other cases. If a person was me'anes his sister, and she doesn't want the eidim to testify, she certainly can't stop them. On the other hand, I'm not sure if you're required to testify in a monetary case if the ba'al doesn't wish it... It's hard to determine where on the spectrum this lies.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky see Chinuch #122.

Comment: @yEz Exactly: Sefer HaChinuch makes a distinction to say that a person isn't chayiv by a dinei mamanos case unless specifically asked to do so by either the court of the litigants. I'm unsure if this case is uniquely a nefashos form of mamanos (and therefore not chayiv until asked), or whether it's a straight nefashos case (and therefore chayiv regardless of external requests).

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky but the Chinuch explicitly says any case of issur is included.  To the extent that you went out of your way to show this is not a case up to the mechila of the father, I don't see what your question is.

Comment: @yEz it's a long chinuch. I only browsed it. Also: not clear if lifnei iver applies when you simply request them not to testify. As long as you aren't lying...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky telling them not to testify is _at least_ עצה רעה.

Comment: @yEz You might be correct about that. Since he hasn't been convicted in court yet, might saving his own soon be tinged with some sort of hatzalas nefashos?

Comment: Is witness tampering not prohibited?

Comment: @SethJ no one is tampering WITH the witnesses (such as feeding them false information, physical coercion, etc.) Asking them not to testify may not be even lifnei iver because you wouldn't be any more culpable than telling someone to steal something (you would be liable if you convinced someone that an act ***wasn't theft,*** but not if you told them to steal).

Comment: Sorry, witness suppression.

Comment: @SethJ is it witness suppression just to ask? I would think as long as you aren't coercing them it isn't...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky is there evidence that in the Torah a child was put to death for having cursed a parent?

Comment: @ninamag is there evidence in the Torah a person was put to death for the sin of kidnapping? The law says the punishment is death, irrespective of whether the crime has historically been prosecuted. Mind you, the parents cannot operate as witnesses and the standard rules of warning would apply...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I just want to understand the nuance, as to why you equated "cursed a parent" (which was my question) to "sin of kidnapping" (which is how you quoted my question)?

Comment: @ninamag no nuance, just an example of another capital offense with a proscribed punishment.